# How to align vectors with different lengths to equal sign?

Tags: math-mode, positioning

I have three vectors, where one is longer than two others :

[image]

My latex code is presented below:

```
\begin{align*}
    row\_offsets[4] = \begin{bmatrix} 
        0 &  \phantom{1} &  2 &  \phantom{1} & 4 & 5 &  \phantom{1} & 7
    \end{bmatrix} \\            
    columns[7] = \begin{bmatrix} 
        0 & 2 & 1 & 3 & 0 & 1 & 3 
    \end{bmatrix} \\
    values[7] = \begin{bmatrix} 
        2 & 9 & 6 & 3 & 3 & 1 & 5
    \end{bmatrix} 
\end{align*}
```

Comment: Add a `&` before the `=` on each line.

Comment: Never do  `row\_offsets` in math italic! the font is designed to make adjacent letters _not_ look like a word but a product of variables, see the `ff`  for a particularly  strong difference. use `\mathit{row\_offsets}`

Comment: Thanks for your advice. i didn't know about that.

Answer (score 3):

Two suggestions/observations:

- Since you're using an `align*` environment, do provide indications where the alignment across rows should occur. E.g, at the `=` symbols. (If you don't provide alignment points, the rows will all be right-aligned, aka ragged-left).
- To typeset names of variables while in math mode, encase the variables -- according to your preferred style -- in either `\mathrm`, `\mathit`, or `\textit` directives.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for 'align*' and 'bmatrix' environments
\newcommand\vn[1]{\textit{#1}} % "variable name"

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
\vn{row\_offsets}[4] &= 
     \begin{bmatrix} 
     0 & \phantom{1} & 2 & \phantom{1} & 4 & 5 & \phantom{1} & 7
     \end{bmatrix} \\            
\vn{columns}[7] &= 
     \begin{bmatrix} 
     0 & 2 & 1 & 3 & 0 & 1 & 3 
     \end{bmatrix} \\
\vn{values}[7] &= 
     \begin{bmatrix} 
     2 & 9 & 6 & 3 & 3 & 1 & 5
     \end{bmatrix} 
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```